# SyncVar not working Unity Networking

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, unity-game-engine

The [SyncVar] attribute is not working for me in my game. I have made sure that:

1. I changed the variable with a command function
2. I correctly added the syncvar attribute and the hook
3. The client can update the variables on the server, but the server is not updating the variable on the client

Here are my scripts:

Player Shooting Script:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerShoot : NetworkBehaviour {

public GameObject shootPosition;

public float shootRange = 100;
public float shootRate = 0.2f;
float nextCheck;

public int damage = 10;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void DetectShooting(){
    if (Time.time > nextCheck && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        nextCheck = Time.time + shootRate;
        CmdShoot ();
    }

}

[Command]
void CmdShoot(){
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray bulletDirection = new Ray (shootPosition.transform.position, transform.forward * shootRange);
    Debug.DrawRay (shootPosition.transform.position, transform.forward * shootRange, Color.blue, 10.0f);
    if (Physics.Raycast (bulletDirection, out hit, 100)) {
        print (hit.transform.name);

        if (hit.transform.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            hit.transform.GetComponent<PlayerHealth> ().DeductHealth (damage);

        }

    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    print (isLocalPlayer);
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    DetectShooting ();
}
}
```

Player Health Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class PlayerHealth : NetworkBehaviour {


public static int maxHealth = 100;

[SyncVar (hook ="UpdateUI")]
public int currentHealth = maxHealth;

public Slider healthBar;

void UpdateUI(int hp){
    healthBar.value = currentHealth;
}

public void DeductHealth(int damage){
    if (isServer)
    currentHealth -= damage;

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //InvokeRepeating ("DeductHealth", 0, 2);
    SetInitialReferences ();
}

void SetInitialReferences(){


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Here are some Screen Shots:

[image: Client Screen Shot After shooting the host]

[image: Host Screen Shot After being shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are hooking the SyncVar with function, you need to pass the variable manually (and do other stuff you wish to do with the new value like checking if hp <= 0).

```
void UpdateUI(int hp){
    currentHealth = hp;
    healthBar.value = currentHealth;
}
```